# Debug assertion fail from initializing an array of a class by user input

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a debug assertion that fails when running `Dinner.Init(Baskets,Bags);`

The error message is vector subscript out of range.

I think it has something to do with the initialization of the variable sized arrays. It takes an unusually long time at the step `Dinner(int num): Apple(num){ }`.

**Are the error message and delay related? Is there a solution for both?**

In foo.h

```
#include <vector>
extern int num1
extern int num2
#define Baskets = num1+num2
#define Bags = num1*2
struct  AppleStruct
{
    std::vector<int> Chunks;
    AppleStruct(){}
    AppleStruct(int num):Chunks(num){ }
};
Class Dinner
{
  std::vector<AppleStruct> Apple;
  public:
  Dinner(){}
  Dinner(int num): Apple(num){ }
  void Init(int num1, int num2);
}

void Dinner::Init(int num1, int num2)
{
int i, j;

    for (i=0; i<num1; i++)          // Fill everything INVALIDs
    {
        for (j=0; j<num2; j++)
        {
            Apple[i].Chunks[j]=1;
        }
    }
}
```

In foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"
int num1;
int num2;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sscanf_s(argv[1],"%d",&num1);
    sscanf_s(argv[2],"%d",&num2);
    AppleStruct(Bags);
    Dinner(Baskets);
    Dinner.Init(Baskets,Bags);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is not valid C++ and does not compile.

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the for loop ,you are assigning values to the vector `chunk` but you have not allocated space for a structure to hold the chunk vector.

```
 for (i=0; i<num1; i++)          // Fill everything INVALIDs
{
    struct AppleStruct newstruct;
    for (j=0; j<num2; j++)
    {
        newstruct.Chunks.push_back(1);
    }
    Apple.push_back(newstruct);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This takes a long time. Is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

Vector is not a regular array, you should push_back to add element first.
 change:

```
Apple[i].Chunks[j] = 1;
```

to

`Apple[i].Chunks[j].push_back(1);`

Also, you need add element to `Apple` too.

Comment: I tried this, but got an red line under Apple, and the error is std::vec<AppleStruct,std::allocator<AppleStruct>> Dinner::Apple, Error: expression must have class type. Why did this happen? Thanks a lot!